# Suggestion to Design Report Scheduler Service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-integration

I am designing a Report Scheduler Service in Java. The task is to look up in database and find if any report is due for execution, at this particular time. 
If yes we need to trigger the Report generation task. 
Report can be scheduled at Specific time (example: Mon @ 18:00 EDT) or Daily (Every Week Day @ 09:00 EDT) or Monthly (Last Day of Month @ 21:00 EDT).

Technology Stack we currently Use:
- Java 6 
- Spring 3.1.3
- Spring Integration 2.2
- Hibernate 4

Current Design Plan: 
- Create Timer Events which populate a message with Timestamp in Database every 5 seconds
- Load all schedules in memory after converting it to UTC Time Zone
- A Spring channel reads this message which arrives every 5 second and Calls a service to look up if any schedule are due to be executed 
- If report due call a service which triggers the report

Need Help regarding tools or Design Suggestions if their is better way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

one option would be to execute this nearly entirely in Spring Integration.

using a JPA inbound channel adapter, a poller can be configured to periodically poll the database and create a message as a consequence, allow you to transform and initiate your job.  all of this can be done within Spring Integration.

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="trigger.channel"
    entity-manager="entityManagerFactory"
    jpa-query="select t from ReportTrigger where ...">
    <int:poller cron="30 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI"/>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="trigger.channel"/>
```